# How to get list of private organization repository from Github API?

Tags: node.js, github, github-api, github-organizations

I want to retrieve private organization repository from Github API V 3.0, I have a private repository in an organization account and when I want to get my repositories, the API just return my public and public-fork repositories but private repositories doesn't retrieve, any idea?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Solved! I was using github-node and called the `getFromUser` method but should've used the `getAll` method for retrieving both private and public repos. It also returns private-organization repositories that I fork.

Answer (score 2):

If the repo is under an organization, you need to retrieve a list of organization repos, not your own user repos. So, instead of using this:

http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories

you need to use this:

http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories

Comment: The problem is in fetching private repos not in organization repos, now I can fetch my public and my organization-public repositories but can't access to my private repos!

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that -- I misread your question. Have you authenticated? You won't see private repos if you don't authenticate. See: http://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

Comment: I was authenticated but I should call another method.